# Anonymity behind VPN/TOR

Tags: vpn

I have been banned from a site, yet when I attempt to connect using Tor behind AVG VPN and keep changing the location the site still recognises my machine/network.
How can this be possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I detect when someone is connecting to my server via Tor?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/88/can-i-detect-when-someone-is-connecting-to-my-server-via-tor)

Comment: additionally a VPN has nothing to do with anonymity and may even harm your anonymity: https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq#IsTorLikeAVPN

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend just using Tor. The VPN is probably being recognized, not you. If needed, use bridges. The VPN destroy Tor purpose

Comment: Agreed, using Tor behind a VPN does nothing but make your internet slow.

Answer (score 1):

I once used AVG for years for my computer protection, but not any longer; now I do not trust them. Their system could not isolate a ‘Trojan’ malicious software and their ‘customer support’ would not or could not help; they failed miserable. However ESET found and curred the problem. In addition, AVG falls within the “14 Eyes” (do YouTube search: “The VPN 14 Eyes Explained” - by Techlore); this is an issue in itself. A good VPN service should have different IP addresses depending what city/server you want to exit from; normally you would be safe to surf, unless something malicious has been placed in your computer. If you are using Tor outside of Tails, this is likely your problem-certainly Tails/Tor would be the solution, if the website allowed an ‘Anonymous’ visitor. You see, ‘Tails’ deletes any software, program, cookies – anything! (even malicious) that a website can install to identify you. Just so you know, ‘Tails’ is an operating itself (with Tor), having some basic pre-installed software like LibreOffice and others. If you can write/create anything, download anything, or import files and even save them to specific folder, but once you shut off your machine, they are wiped away—no traces of them. What ever work one does in ‘Tails”, needs to be transferred to a thumb-drive before the computer is shut down.

With that said, I trust NordVPN; they are in Panama and do not fall within the “5, 7 or 14 Eyes” and is Linux compatible also having Tor configured in conjunction with their VPN as an option.